# htaccess Help required redirecting old deleted links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a site (e.g. mysite.com) and old versions of the site under a directory are still appearing in search engines (e.g. mysite.com/oldsecton/something.html). There are too many of these links to remove from search engine finds.

- I want everything in the /oldsection to redirect back to mysite.com/index.html
- i.e. everything in the /oldsection should go to index.html located one directory path back
- I have tried different variations of .htaccess inside /oldsection such as

  ```
    ErrorDocument 404 ../index.html
    ErrorDocument 404 mysite.com/index.html
    etc...
  ```

None of them seem to be successfull.

This should be a simple task but I keep getting an Internal Server Error or a ErrorDocument error.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/oldsection/.htaccess` have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: On behalf of all our lost users and myself, thank you anubhava!

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.